# My teacher said this isn't normalized and I can't understand why

Tags: vba, ms-access

My database is about a gaming team, and I have a table called games played, where my columns are game ID, game date, map, opponent, our score and opponents score.
The teacher claims that opponents score should be in another table because it's connected to the opponent column and I can't understand why and how it should look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say it salopp, normalized means that you prevent any duplikates. For example you have a person and related phone numbers. You could do it like this:

```
Person    Type     Number
  A      Mobile    001234
  A      Mobile    004444
  A      Phone     005555
```

You have now Person and Type as duplikates. So you apply the following structure:

```
PersonID    Person
   1          A

PersonID    PhoneID
   1           1
   1           2
   1           3

PhoneID      TypeID    Number
   1           1       001234
   2           1       004444
   3           2       005555

TypeID        Type
  1          Mobile
  2          Phone
```

Now if you link everything together (PersonID to PersonID, PhoneID to PhoneID, TypeID to TypeID) you get the first table I wrote. This structure also ensures that your dependencies are properly enforced by database integrity constraints (This is needed for update, delete, etc... querys).

If you apply this system on your gaming team you could do it like this:

- A table with Team and  TeamID
- A table which links teams to results: GameID, HomeTeamID, GuestTeamID, ResultID
- A table with Results and ResultID
- A table for GameID for more informations about the game (like time, place, etc...)
- A table with TeamID and PlayerID
- A table with PlayerID and more player informations (Here you have to consider if a player can play in more than one team)

Comment: Is combining the table of the game information and the table links teams to result less normlized? Because it seem's odd to me to split those since they have the same key.

Comment: That depends on your data. Global game information like day and place shouldnt be in the same table as the result. But the time can be in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

1. Table 1: All about Games - have all possible game attributes here. This becomes your dimension table.
2. Table 2: All about Players - have all possible players (incl. opponents as they are also players) here. This becomes your dimension table.
3. Table 3: All about events - have all possible events (match related) here. This becomes your fact table.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean, should I split it or shouldn't I? And if I should how and why

Comment: The above is a normalized version of your question. This is called as 3NF.

Comment: This table setup will get you further towards your goal. Note that Table 3 is going to have a GameID field that refers to Table 1, and also two PlayerID fields that refer to Table 2. GameID is a value in Table 1 that uniquely identifies a game. PlayerID is a value in Table 2 that uniquely identifies a player, whether opponent or not.